# Weapon skills with unspecified traits in L5R, 2e?

Tags: weapons, l5r-2e

In Legend of the Five Rings (2nd edition), for bojitsu (and I believe someone was looking for naginata as well) we looked for the specific trait that would tell us what dice to keep, however in none of the descriptions nor tables is there a specific trait mentioned; it says variable, all others however are specified.

Where can I find these kind of specifications?

Edit:
From the Player's Guide, pg93:

> **Bujitsu (varies):** The weapons skills of the l5r rpg cover weapons with simiolar size and weight distribution. we have collected the entirety of them for clarification. For game purposes, if a character has one of the skills, he is assumed to have the same rank while using all weapons listed with it. For exaple a samurai with a Kenjutsu 2 rolls 2 dice when he uses a katana, a wakizashi, or a no-dachi.

It then lists each specialty with the corresponding weapons, and it ends with a note on ninjutsu.

From the same page:

> **Athletics (varies):** ... If a character is running, for instance, and wants to test his speed, he uses athletics/reflexes. However, if he wants to test his endurance, he would roll athletics/stamina.

Comment: I invite someone with a better understanding of l5r than me to reword the title. Currently I think it'd be better off as "Where can I find out the skills for weapons with unspecified traits?" but I am not sure if I would be using the right words there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall, all weapon skills except for Kyujutsu are based on Agility (Kyujutsu is Reflexes). I don't have rulebooks with me to give you a page number, but it should be spelled out in the skill section.

(edit) had a chance to look at the 2e Player's Book, and found your answers. It's a bit scattered about, but...

Easy answer right up front - a Naginata uses Yarijutsu, as it's kind of like a spear.

Secondly, on the character sheet at the back of the book, To Hit Rolls, actually says 'Roll Weapon Skill, Keep Agility'.

Thirdly, although Bujutsu on p93 doesn't specify what each attribute individual weapon skill uses, the few listed weapon skills DO specify. For instance, Kenjutsu lists Agility. Kyujutsu lists Reflexes, while Yomanri (Gaijin archery) lists Agility. Specific Weapon Specialisation also lists Agility.

Lastly, on p161, underAttack and Defense, it says 'the Trait used is Agility, except in unusual cases'. Ranged Weapons on p163 then mentions that Kyujutsu uses Reflexes instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what it says on the character sheet, but precisely because it specified "variable" under bujutsu I wanted to check, we've been using Agility in the interim.
Thank you

Comment: In theory, the GM could specify any attribute, depending on the circumstances. For instance, if you were trying to wait, and hit something as it moved past you, Reflexes might be more appropriate. But in general circumstances, Agility is the default.

Answer (score 1):

This may come as a reiteration of prior answers/comments, but a weapon skill "varies" only depending on its use.  Most commonly **they use Agility as the trait when attacking**, with the lone exception of bows (kyujutsu) and even then it can be changed.  I believe my reference book is 1st edition but there are few differences except for the game logo between 1st and 2nd.  And in my book, p.70 it says (in summation) that any skills should be self explanitory unless a specific mention is made for it.  Create a "-jutsu" skill for a set of closely grouped weapons and unless there are special rules for using all weapons of those class, it's treated as the same.

Comment: Actually, there were a number of mechanical changes between 1st and 2nd ed, although the skill system is largely unchanged. Also, I believe the original poster is simply asking which attribute to use with weapon skills.

Comment: To quote my answer: "...they use agility as the trait when attacking..."

Comment: Sorry - wasn't saying you were inaccurate, just that the accurate answer was obscured by the extraneous detail.

Comment: Put the core answer in bold.  Thank you for pointing out something I overlooked.